# Comic strip about three-legged aliens that invade and trap people in bubbles

Tags: story-identification, comics

I think this must have appeared around the early to middle 1970s, and was serialised in a weekly UK comic (sorry, can't remember which one).

The story was set in a small town, where some aliens invaded. They had three legs, and their arms ended in suckers rather than hands (bit like the end of the non-deadly arm on a Dalek). If any human got too close, then blew some kind of large bubble from the suckers that settled over the person, trapping them inside.

Don't remember much more of it than that, other that at the very end, some common threat caused the humans and aliens to work together (a young boy was the hero as I remember). Right at the end, the boy held one of the alien's suckers and shouted triumphantly "*You did it!*" to which the alien replied (in a thought rather than speech bubble) "*No, we did it*."

Anyone any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You ever heard of Chicken Little?

Comment: @Jeff Was that comment directed at me or MrLister? If me, yes I've heard of him, but don't see the significance. Please explain what you meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a strip called *The Jellymen* in an old British comic called *The Beezer*. I think they "bubbled" some people in the way described - though iirc it turned out to be due to misunderstandings, and they were really friendly.

Comment: Thank you! I'd given up hope of getting an answer to this one. That was exactly the one I meant.

Comment: Incidentally, istr the Jellyman's response to the boy as "No, not I, but thou". However these are very old memories and that one may come from something else.

Comment: I don't remember it that clearly. Shame, I'd love to read it again. I wonder if there is any way of getting it now.

Comment: There's quite a bit online about British comics, but nowhere near everything. I can only suggest googling "Beezer" and "jellymen" to see what turns up.

Comment: Yeah, did quite a bit of that yesterday, and found a few isolated images, but nothing that gave the whole story. I'd happily buy a book if I could find one.